# Improper Integral, show that $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{\theta^2}f(\frac{x}{\theta})\,d\theta=x$.

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Let $f$ be a function, $x>0$ and $\theta>0$, and suppose $\int_{0}^{\infty}tf(t)\,dt=1$

How could I show that $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{\theta^2}f(\frac{x}{\theta}) \, d\theta =x$?

I try substituting with $u=\frac{x}{\theta}$ and then $du=-\frac{x}{\theta^2} \, d\theta$, and the integral becomes:
$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{\theta^2}f(\frac{x}{\theta}) \, d\theta=\int_\infty^0 -xf(u)\,du=\int_0^\infty xf(u) \, du$...
but then I don't seem to be getting anywhere and I don't know how to use that $\int_0^\infty tf(t) \,dt=1$
...
Thanks.

Comment: are you sure that the condition is not $\int_0^{\infty} f(t)=1$  instead ?

Comment: your integral is = $\theta$.

Comment: It's false as stated.

Comment: @Chilango That's the variable of integration.

Comment: As tired alluded to above you need to start with the condition $\int_0^\infty f(t) dt = 1$ to get the desired conclusion. From your condition you only get $\int_0^\infty f\left(\frac{x}{\theta}\right)\frac{x^3}{\theta^3}d\theta = x$

Comment: zhw, some counterexample?

Comment: Counter-example: $f(x) = 4e^{-2x}$. Then $\int_0^\infty tf(t)dt = 1$, but your integral with $x=1$ gives $2 \not= 1$.

Comment: @zhw. of course you're right., I misread the problem. Looking again, I don't think the problem is well-posed.

Comment: Since the only thing you know about $f$ is $\int_0^\infty t f(t)\; dt$, the only integrals of the form $\int_a^b g(\theta) f(u(\theta))\; d\theta$ that you can evaluate are those that transform to a multiple of $\int_0^\infty t f(t)\; dt$ by substitution $t = u(\theta)$.

Comment: Thanks. I've already found another counterexample (With a normal curve). So, it's false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{\theta^2} f\left(\frac x \theta \right)\,d\theta= \int_\infty^0 x f(u)\,(-du) = \overbrace{\int_0^\infty xf(u)\,du = x \int_0^\infty f(u)\,du}
$$

The step under the $\overbrace{\text{overbrace}}$ is valid because $x$ is a constant, i.e. it does not change as $u$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$, or as $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$.

To finish this off, you would have to know that $\int_0^\infty f(u)\,du=1$.